# Web Chat Routing - Via Pre Chat form on ths same page

Tags: community, chat, pre-chat

We have x2 channels for our chat support. Tech support and Web Support.

We currently use a form to separate out the support channels and change the Button ID using this function below based on a simple pre-chat form.

```
        embedded_svc.settings.directToButtonRouting = function(prechatFormData) {
        
            var e = document.getElementById("initialRecordType");
            var selection = e.value;
     
            if(selection == 'techsupport') { return "5731I000000h6Xa"; }
            if(selection == 'websupport') { return "5731I0000005T8k"; }
            // returns a different button ID based on the pre-chat form
        };
```

But this doesn't change the ticket type when the ticket comes through to salesforce. It only changes who the chat goes too. I want it to also update the ticket type. I've tested and this is done here below.

```
        embedded_svc.init(

        'https://picts.my.salesforce.com',

        'https://licencemanager.force.com/support',

        gslbBaseURL,

        '00D1I000001eh9q',

        'Technical_Chat',
        // 'Website_Chat' - This replaces the above line
        {

            baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la2-c1-iad.salesforceliveagent.com/content',

            deploymentId: '5721I000000hARe',

            buttonId: '5731I000000h6Xa',

            baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la2-c1-iad.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',

            eswLiveAgentDevName: 'Technical_Chat',
            // eswLiveAgentDevName: 'EmbeddedServiceLiveAgent_Parent04I1I000000bnjGUAQ_172c8e1a3c1', - This replaces the above line

            isOfflineSupportEnabled: true

        }

    );
```

This is done at run time so adding if functions based on the form is useless as it hasn't changed on load. I need a function to edit these settings above or a way to edit on the fly.

I know I can set up 2 pages and have different code on each page but this isn't what my boss wants.

Can't seem to see any help on this online. Can anybody help me?

Thank you
John